# "ref.child is not a function"

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm trying to implement a simple cloud function which, when a new user is added to my /users path without any default values, adds a default object structure to that new user.

If no children are specified under that user's name, the method should simply return.

```
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    admin.initializeApp();

    exports.defaultUser = functions.database.ref('/users/{any}')
        .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

            var ref = functions.database.ref('/users');
            ref.child('%s', snapshot.key).once('value', function 
    (snapshot) {
                var exists = (snapshot.val() !== null);
                if (!exists) return;
            });

            const userObj = {
                name: "default",
                mail: "default",
                pwd: "default",
                token: "default",
                groups: {},
                plants: {},
                points: 0
            }

            return snapshot.ref.child.set(userObj);
        });
```

This returns "ref.child is not a function" in the function logs.

I'm very new to javascript and firebase, so this must look very confusing to someone experienced.

Comment: If you are new to JavaScript, Cloud Functions for Firebase is not the best way to learn it. I recommend first reading the [Firebase documentation for Web developers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) and/or taking the [Firebase codelab for Web developer](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/). They cover many basic JavaScript, Web and Firebase interactions. You could also use the Admin SDK in a local Node.js process, which can be debugged with a local debugger. After those you'll be much better equipped to write code for Cloud Functions too.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations. I will make sure to get some Javascript basics down before approaching this project again.

Answer (score 0):

You're either looking for:

```
snapshot.ref.set(userObj);
```

Or:

```
snapshot.ref.child("somekey").set(userObj);
```

Also note that you'll want to use a transaction to prevent a race condition where you overwrite the data as the user is writing it.